# relative paths with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, relative-path

I'm trying to run a small app locally (xampp). I'm running it from localhost/csf.local/ and I have the following in the .htaccess in that root dir:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home.php
```

Now, all the relative paths in home.php point to localhost/, rather than localhost/csf.local/. Can anyone help me get this straight? Thank you.

SOLVED------------

I managed to sort this out myself.

I added this to the  tag of home.php, so it basically 'prefixes' every relative path with this base:

```
<base href='/csf.local/'; />
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: When you solve your own question (and nobody else did), it is acceptable and even encouraged to answer your own question and mark that as the accepted answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the question was not solved. I used a completely different approach.

Comment: I see your point: you came up with a solution of sorts but it's not really a direct answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
RewriteBase /csf.local/
```

to set the base dir which the RewriteRules use

Comment: I tried this, as well (just after the rewriteengine on) and it seems to have no effect. Any other suggestions?

Comment: That was the only solution I could mention.